# How to implement Jquery checkbox check all/uncheck all function with a checkbox in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a checkbox in a loop that I wanted to check all and uncheck all using jquery. I have implemented a Jquery check all and uncheck all function, however, it only check the first checkbox in the loop after checking the checkall labeled checkbox. How would I able to implement this correctly? Codes are shown below. Thanks.

View:

```
<div><input type="checkbox" class="check_all"> Check all</div>
  <?php
      $cnt=0;
   echo form_open('students/del_student/'.$tennant_id);
    foreach($data_student as $row)
    {
      $cnt++;
      echo"<input type='hidden' name='course_occasion_id'   value=".$row->course_occasion_id.">";
      ?>
       <address>

     <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span2"><input type='checkbox' name='student_id[]'id="student_id" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>"  ></div>
      <div class="span4"><?php echo anchor("students/student/$row->id/$tennant_id",$row->first_name);?></div>
      <div class="span4"><?php echo $row->last_name;?> </div>
      <div class="span2"><?php echo $row->status;?> </div>
     </div>
     </address>
    <?php
     }
     ?>
```

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

   $('.check_all').on('click', function () {


    $("#student_id").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));


   });
  </script>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: IDs must be unique on context page, use class instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating each of your checkboxes with the same id:

```
id="student_id"
```

ID should be unique across the page.

Instead, change this to a class, e.g. `class="student_id"` and change your selector to look for the class:

```
$(".student_id").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
```

Comment: `$(this).prop('checked') === this.checked`

Answer (score 1):

The `id`s have to be unique in the document.

In jQuery, Instead of `#id` use `.class` and in HTML use `class=...` instead of `id=...`.

```
$(".student_id").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
```

Take a look at [**the difference between `id` and `class`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) in HTML:

- `id = name [CS]`

  > This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name **must be unique** in a document.
- `class = cdata-list [CS]`

  > This attribute assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. **Any number of elements may be assigned the same class** name or names. Multiple class names must be separated by white space characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` instead..because `id` is unique

```
  $('.check_all').on('click', function () {

    $(".std").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));

   });
```

and your html

```
<div class="span2"><input type='checkbox' name='student_id[]' class="std" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>"  ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below javascript helps to check uncheck all checkbox options in a loop.

```
function FunCheckAll(obj) {            
if (obj.checked) {
    $('.chkSelectAll').each(function (i, e) {
        if ($(e).is(":not(:visible())") == false) {
            $(e).prop('checked', true);                        
        }
    });
}
else {
    $('.chkSelectAll').each(function (i, e) {
        $(e).prop('checked', false);                    
    });
}
```

}

chkSelectAll is the name of class used with the checkboxes.